# Eager Loading : How to disable specific fields of included table

Tags: postgresql, crud, sequelize.js, eager-loading

I am trying to do **Eager Loading** in Sequelize with PostgreSQL where I need to find the **Users** which have a given specific **Mail** id or basically, i am performing find operation on **Mail** model while using *include* to include **User** model

UserModel :

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, Sequelize) {


    var User = sequelize.define('User', {
        userId: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        firstname: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            require: true
        },
        lastname: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            require: true
        },
        age: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            require: true
        },
        phone: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            require: true
        },
        location: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            require: true
        },
        createdAt: {
            type: Sequelize.DATE,
            defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW
        },
        updatedAt: {
            type: Sequelize.DATE,
            defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW
        }
    });

    return User;

};
```

MailModel :

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, Sequelize) {



    var User = require('./User.js')(sequelize, Sequelize)


    var Mail = sequelize.define('Mail', {
        name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            require: true
        }
    });


    Mail.belongsTo(User);

    return Mail;
};
```

MailController :

```
var db = require('../services/db.js');

module.exports = {
    create: function (req, res, next) {

        var Mailm = db.MailModel;
        var name = req.body;
        try {

            db.sequelize.sync().then(function () {

                Mailm.create(name).then(function (found) {

                    return res.json({
                        success: true,
                        message: found.get({
                            plain: true
                        })
                    });
                })

            });

        } catch (ex) {
            res.json({
                success: false,
                exception: ex
            });
            return;
        }

    },
query: function (req, res, next) {

        var Mailm = db.MailModel;
        var Userm = db.UserModel;
        var name = req.body;


        var option = {};
        option.where = name;
        option.include = [{
            model: Userm

        }];

        try {
            Mailm.findAll(option).then(function (found) {
                console.log(found);
                return res.json({
                    success: true,
                    message: found
                });

            });
        } catch (ex) {
            res.json({
                success: false,
                exception: ex
            });
            return;
        }
    }



};
```

It is returning me the records of both User and Mail table in exactly the right way .

> Output :

```
{
"success": true,
"message":[
{
"id": 2,
"name": "Mailb2",
"createdAt": "2015-07-30T07:32:51.807Z",
"updatedAt": "2015-07-30T07:32:51.807Z",
"UserUserId": 2,
     "User":{
              "userId": 2,
              "firstname": "Prerna",
              "lastname": "Jain",
              "age": 20,
              "phone": "9812123456",
              "location": "Sirsa",
              "createdAt": "2015-07-30T07:30:48.000Z",
              "updatedAt": "2015-07-30T07:30:48.000Z"
             }
         }
 ]
}
```

But I want to **disable *createdAt* and *updatedAt*** fields of **User** table so that it does not give me these two fields in the output for User.

I have tried a lot as of how to do this but still in vain.Can anyone please help me out.

Comment: Hi Prerna Jain Try using the [Delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) command on the object that your returning through your db operation.Delete the fields you don't want return in JSON format and print the corresponding object in JSON. Let me know if this worked

Answer (score 0):

I bet this is coming late, add attribute/properties to your models called timestamps, it accepts a boolean as a value. For example:

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, Sequelize) {



    var User = require('./User.js')(sequelize, Sequelize)


    var Mail = sequelize.define('Mail', {
        name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            require: true
        }
    }, 
    {
    // This does the magic

        timestamps: false,
    });


    Mail.belongsTo(User);

    return Mail;
};
```

Also, add it to the User model:

```
    var User = sequelize.define('User', {
        userId: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        firstname: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            require: true
        },
        lastname: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            require: true
        },
        age: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            require: true
        },
        phone: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            require: true
        },
        location: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            require: true
        },
        createdAt: {
            type: Sequelize.DATE,
            defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW
        },
        updatedAt: {
            type: Sequelize.DATE,
            defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW
        }
    }, 
     {
timestamps: false
  });

    return User;

};
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```js
    Model.findAll({
      attributes: { exclude: ['baz'] }
    });
```

more examples with attributes - http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/#attributes